# SQL query taking 1 minute and 35 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing the query on SQL server on hosting and it is taking 1 minute and 35 seconds. And the no, of rows of retrieval are 18000. Still it is taking too much time. Query is

```
select ID,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       Branch,
       EnquiryID,
       Course,
       College,
       Mobile,
       ExamID,
       EntranceID,
       Entrance,
       Venue,
       RegNo,
       VenueID,
       Exam,
       Gender,
       row_number() over (partition by EnquiryID order by ID asc) as AttemptNO
from AGAM_View_AOPList
order by EnquiryID
```

TABLE SCHEMAS

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_AceOFPace](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EnquiryID] [int] NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[MiddleName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[BranchID] [int] NULL,
[Branch] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[CourseID] [int] NULL,
[ExamID] [int] NULL,
[Exam] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[EntranceID] [int] NULL,
[Entrance] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[RegNo] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[EntranceCode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[ExamDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[UserID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[EntranceFees] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[VenueID] [int] NULL,
[Venue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ChequeNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Bank] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGAM_AceOFPace] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
[ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

```
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_AceOFPace]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AGAM_AceOFPace_AGAM_Inquiry] FOREIGN KEY([EnquiryID])
```

REFERENCES [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry] ([ID])
GO

```
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_AceOFPace] CHECK CONSTRAINT   [FK_AGAM_AceOFPace_AGAM_Inquiry]
```

GO

SECOND TABLE

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RegNo] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[BranchID] [int] NULL,
[Category] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[CourseID] [int] NULL,
[EntranceFees] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[EntranceID] [int] NULL,
[UserID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ReminderDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Reminder] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Mobile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MiddleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Landline] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[DOB] [datetime] NULL,
[Gender] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PfBatchTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[SourceOfInquiry] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ExStudentID] [int] NULL,
[InquiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ReceiptNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RawID] [int] NULL,
[Deleted] [int] NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[LastModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[College] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Qualification] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[RptNo] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGAM_Inquiry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
[ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT   [FK_AGAM_Inquiry_AGAM_Branch] FOREIGN KEY([BranchID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AGAM_Branch] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AGAM_Inquiry_AGAM_Branch]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT   [FK_AGAM_Inquiry_AGAM_Course] FOREIGN KEY([CourseID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AGAM_Course] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AGAM_Inquiry_AGAM_Course]
    GO

     ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT  [FK_AGAM_Inquiry_AGAM_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AGAM_Users] ([UserID])
   GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AGAM_Inquiry_AGAM_Users]
   GO
```

Comment: and the view contains joining of two tables simple join

Comment: Show us the table definition (`create table ...`), the definition of all indexes and the execution plan.

Comment: paste your schema and desired output

Comment: The query you are using to query the view is not whats interesting, you should be trying to run the query what is defined in the view and include execution plan when running the query and then see what costs most and try to improve the query inside the view.

Comment: SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT AP.ID, AP.FirstName, AP.LastName, AP.Branch, AP.EnquiryID,
                          (SELECT     Name
                            FROM          dbo.AGAM_Course
                            WHERE      (ID = AP.CourseID)) AS Course, AI.College, AI.Mobile, AP.ExamID, AP.EntranceID, AP.RegNo, AP.VenueID, AP.Exam, AI.Gender, AP.BranchID, AP.CourseID, 
                      AP.CreatedDate, AI.Status, AP.Entrance, AP.Venue
FROM         dbo.AGAM_AceOFPace AS AP INNER JOIN
                      dbo.AGAM_Inquiry AS AI ON AI.ID = AP.EnquiryID
ORDER BY AP.EnquiryID

Comment: Aha! Sub-Selects! Are there respective indices on all the columns used to join and all `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: YES THAT COURSE TABLE CONTAINS INDICES

Comment: show us the code for those

Comment: CONSTRAINT [PK_AGAM_AceOFPace] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_AceOFPace]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AGAM_AceOFPace_AGAM_Inquiry] FOREIGN KEY([EnquiryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AGAM_Inquiry] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AGAM_AceOFPace] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AGAM_AceOFPace_AGAM_Inquiry]
GO

Comment: I POSTED VIEW , TABLE STRUCTURE ABOVE PLEASE CHECK

Comment: Is there a reason why the course name gets selected with subquery rather tha inner join?

Comment: The code should be pasted into the question, not a comment. If I weren't on my iPhone, I'd do it.

Comment: What does the query execution plan look like?

Comment: Couple of things to try:
* you say this is hosted, does the timing include sending the data 'over the internet' to you ? (try doing the select with an INTO #dummy and see how long that takes)

* have you tried running the query without the course sub-query ?
* have you looked at the query-plan ? 
* are your statistics up-to-date (run sp_updatestats)

. Oh, and please remove the ORDER BY from the view definition; it doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with changing the view to this?

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    AP.ID, 
    AP.FirstName, 
    AP.LastName, 
    AP.Branch, 
    AP.EnquiryID, 
    AC.Name,
    AI.College, 
    AI.Mobile, 
    AP.ExamID, 
    AP.EntranceID, 
    AP.RegNo, 
    AP.VenueID, 
    AP.Exam, 
    AI.Gender, 
    AP.BranchID, 
    AP.CourseID, 
    AP.CreatedDate, 
    AI.Status, 
    AP.Entrance, 
    AP.Venue 
FROM dbo.AGAM_AceOFPace AS AP 
INNER JOIN dbo.AGAM_Inquiry AS AI ON AI.ID = AP.EnquiryID 
INNER JOIN dbo.AGAM_Course as AC on AC.ID = AP.CourseId
ORDER BY AP.EnquiryID
```

Comment: Well if that query is slow then there is not much you can do to optimize it.

Comment: Isn't an ORDER BY in a view 'bad news' anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on EnquiryId and CourseID?

Seeing as you are joining,  ordering and partitioning by it you really should.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_AGAM_AceOFPace_EnquiryID
ON AGAM_AceOFPace (EnquiryID)

CREATE INDEX IDX_AGAM_AceOFPace_CourseID
ON AGAM_AceOFPace (CourseID)
```